# How to add svg file extension on a beamer latex?

Tags: svg, latex, inkscape, beamer

I am doing a beamer latex presentation and I would like to know how is it possible to add directly a svg graphic on it. I know that it is possible to convert the svg file to pdf format and then include it to beamer, but I want to include the svg file directly (without convert it to pdf format).

The code must looks like:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame SVG example}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[\textwidth]{graphic.svg}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SVG](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) package to achieve that. It will convert your .svg on the fly using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) (which needs to be installed on your computer). It will re-export your figures if the .svg file is changed.

A minimal example could look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{svg}
\setsvg{inkscape = "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -D}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \includesvg[width=0.7\textwidth]{path/to/mysvgimage}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are some things to consider, such as text formatting and alignment. Have a look at the documentation of the SVG package.

You also need to make sure that your allow latex to call Inkscape with

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

or

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```